# Is "Chicken Box" an appropriate term for a Yes/No dialogue with a warning?

Tags: gui-design

We have a mixin so named, and since my project requires more of these types of dialogue boxes, I created a lot of tickets for myself with the term "Chicken Box" in the titles.

[image: Chicken Box with warning message]

It's basically just a Yes/No dialogue with as ominous a warning as we can construct. The semantics are that the box gives the user a chance to chicken out on calling the callback action.

I've been assured that it's a common term, but I can't find any such usages via Google. Is this a proper term for this type of UI element? Is there a more common term?

Comment: I think i'll call it a chicken box from now on, formerly known as a confirmation dialog.

Comment: It should be mentioned that these are kind of an [anti-pattern](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39337/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-user-confirmation) in UX design. They're easy on the programmer, but usually not the best option to actually prevent the user from making mistakes.

Comment: This example is wordy and not really funny.

Comment: On the anti-pattern matter, we want a simple UI, and for the workflow, there is no undo. Since this is something we expect to be done about once a week, we want to provide the user with a bit of a buffer before they actually complete the action, as well as give them a bit of interaction so they will know something is going on (see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61592/building-out-ui-for-org-to-kick-off-remote-process-how-to-display-feedback ). The example reflects my sense of humor: dry and a bit over-the-top in places.

Comment: For the record, I found my way here after hearing the term used in conversation. Googling "Chicken box" made me hungry, but googling "UI Chicken Box" brought me here and satisfied my curiosity.

Comment: For the record, I found my way here after hearing the term used in conversation. Googling "Chicken box" made me hungry, but googling "UI Chicken Box" brought me here and satisfied my curiosity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is

## "Confirmation Dialog"

A simple google search on this term shows numerous examples of the paradigm you described.

[**Confirmation Box Google Images**](https://www.google.com/search?q=confirmation+dialog&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=RObjU6faDtGTyASknIDQAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1042&bih=621)

---

"Chicken Box" by contrast shows delicious golden brown fried chicken

[**Chicken Box Google Images**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1042&bih=621&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=chicken+box&oq=chicken+box&gs_l=img.3..0l10.33437.34597.0.34909.11.10.0.1.1.0.124.923.9j1.10.0....0...1c.1.51.img..0.11.926.fr1ffi0eU3w)

Comment: Sounds a bit more descriptive. Plus one.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a simple **Dialog Box**.

> Dialog boxes consist of a title bar (to identify the command, feature, or program where a dialog box came from), an optional main instruction (to explain the user's objective with the dialog box), various controls in the content area (to present options), and commit buttons (to indicate how the user wants to commit to the task).

More specifically a **Modal dialog box**.

> require users to complete and close before continuing with the owner window. These dialog boxes are best used for critical or infrequent, one-off tasks that require completion before continuing.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't think there's a "proper term for this type of UI element" because you are looking for a specific name for your specific scenario's usage.  I could have the same UI and the purpose of it is to test if user is brave enough to click YES; I could call it Brave Box.

> Is “Chicken Box” an appropriate term for a Yes/No dialogue with a warning?

So yes, what ever you call it would be appropriate because you are identifying the command, feature of the box.  Of course, I assume, user won't see this **Title**, just for your reference.

Comment: Right, wasn't going to use that for the user, it was more of a meta-title. Plus one!

Answer (score 2):

"Last-Chance Dance Dialog" if you want to be cute or clever.

Comment: Meh. I'll give you a vote if someone else votes for the others. So they need probably two votes to guarantee you didn't vote them up then take it back. BTW, you're at 666 rep. Kinda scary.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked in software dev for more than 2 decades, I am used to calling it a chickenbox.  I like the term and continue to use it.